# Add conditional margin in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to add a margin-top when the Button gets to the next line using display:flex. (after resizing to 1667px, this can vary for different displays and resolutions)

[before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpGQe.png)

[after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMXJx.png)

[what I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEE8J.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Don’t just show images.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive criticism. This is my first post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `margin-bottom: 5px;` on all the inputs instead of adding margin top to the button.

If items can stand on one line you won't see the difference but if the button go to next line there will be a margin upon it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there no way to make the margin dependent on the resizing that is happening? A fixed margin would result into an increase of height. The buttons would not be centered anymore.

Comment: The way that I do would be to set some css media queries and apply some style according to the screen size. Like @media screen and (max-width: 1667px) {button: margin-top: 5px;}. But you have to be sure that this is exactly at this point that the button go to line. You could decide to force it to go to line by yourself too.

Comment: If you want to create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) with your code, so I can check it and advise you on what would be great to do :)

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply. I thought about doing it this way. But then I was not sure if the 1667px might be something different on other screens and resolutions. Forcing the button to go down would be better I think. I currently have no access to the code.